# Decomposition of product of exterior products

Tags: tensor-powers

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space of dimension n.

What is the kernel of the map

$$\bigwedge^p V \otimes \bigwedge^q V ----> \bigwedge^{p+q} V$$ ?

(here $p+q< n$)

Thanks..
Jyoti

Comment: This question would be a better fit at http://math.stackexchange.com - see http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatquestions

Comment: You can add $$ to the math formulas.

Comment: I can't give you an answer, but if you look at Fulton and Harris, *Representation Theory*, chapter 15, you will find the general method to decompose representations of $GL(V)$ into irreducibles.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. Anyway, there is an elegant answer. Assuming you understand the classification of irreps of GL(V) by partitions, Pieri's rule tells you that $\bigwedge^p V \otimes \bigwedge^q V \cong \bigoplus S_{2^a 1^b} V$, where $2a+b=p+q$ and $a \leq \min(p,q)$. The map to $\bigwedge^{p+q} V$ is projection onto the $(a,b)=(0,p+q)$ summand, so the kernel is the direct sum of the other components.

Comment: Here $S_{\lambda}$ is the Schur functor.

Comment: I voted to reopen.  I agree with David -- I think people jumped the gun on voting to close it.

Comment: Hmm, on a 2nd look I think I misread/misunderstood the question, though I still think it could do with added context for why the question is being asked. Anyway, voting to re-open (volte-face)

Comment: I'm confused -- what is the map?  Are we to assume wedge product? 